# Regex Replacing Characters with HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this sample string where I would like to replace the star with an opening and closing strong tag using regular expressions in JavaScript:

```
To increase search results, use the 8** prefix.
877 and 866 will result in more matches than 800 and 888 prefixes.
*Note*: The pattern for a custom number can be more than 7 digits. For example: 1-800-Mat-tres(s)
```

The ideal output would be:

```
To increase search results, use the 8** prefix.
877 and 866 will result in more matches than 800 and 888 prefixes.
<strong>Note</strong>: The pattern for a custom number can be more than 7 digits. For example: 1-800-Mat-tres(s)
```

The only caveat being that if there are two starts in a row (like 8**), that they not be replaced with the strong tags.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all yourself?

Comment: @AdamZalcman good point. I need to encourage this more.

Comment: Yes, I tried 

    var thisContent = thisContent.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g,'<strong>$&</strong>');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this?

```
\*(\S[^\*]+\S)\*
```

The `+` means 1 or more, so will only match if there is something between the `*`.

The `[^\*]` means anything that's not a star `*`.

**UPDATE**
I've updated the regex above to specify that it doesn't match nonwhite space character's in between the `*` and and the first and last characters of each match. This prevent's the highlighted bit below from incorrectly matching:

8*`* prefix.
877 and 866 will result in more matches than 800 and 888 prefixes. *`Note*

Here is the same regex with comments (in javascript)

```
"\\*" +       // Match the character “*” literally
"\\S" +       // Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
"[^\\*]" +    // Match any character that is NOT a * character
   "+" +        // Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"\\S" +       // Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character”
"\\*"         // Match the character “*” literally
```

Finally, here is an example of the javascript you could use:

```
yourStringData.replace(/\*(\S[^\*]+\S)\*/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

Just replace the `yourStringData` with a variable containing the data you want to run the replace against.

Comment: This regex pattern is excellent. The only issue that I found was that it didn't remove the original star there. So the content is properly wrapped in the strong tag, but with the stars still inside.

Comment: More specifically this is the replace I'm using:

`code`var thisContent = thisContent.replace(/\*\S[^\*]+\S\*/g, "<strong>$&</strong>");`code`

Comment: @SkyOut i think the reason you are getting the `*`'s in the replacement is that it needs a group adding around the `\S`'s like this: `\*(\S[^\*]+\S)\*` - I think.... let me know if that works.

Comment: @SkyOut i've updated the answer with the above change and an example of how to call it using javascript.

Comment: @SkyOut no worries, i've upvoted your question, so you should now have over 10 rep... which if i remember correctly means you can now upvote answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

If there are always *words* between the `*`'s:

```
your_string.replace(/\*(\w+)\*/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if there is anything else between the `*`'s - like spaces or any kind of punctuation (which i imagine there will be?). It will also match anything between `**` and the start of a `*text*` - which is the opposite of what it should match