# Replace a specific character from a string with HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, replace

Having a text input, if there is a specific character it must convert it to a tag. For example, the special character is `*`, the text between 2 special characters must appear in italic.

For example:

```
This is *my* wonderful *text*
```

must be converted to:

```
This is <i>my</i> wonderful <i>text</i>
```

So I've tried like:

```
const arr = "This is *my* wonderful *text*";
 if (arr.includes('*')) {
      arr[index] = arr.replace('*', '<i>');
    }
```

it is replacing the star character with `<i>` but doesn't work if there are more special characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916554/regex-replacing-characters-with-html-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create `wrapper` and thereafter use regular expression to detect if there is any word that is surrounded by `*` and simply replace it with any tag, in your example is `<i>` tag so just see the following

### Example

```js
let str = "This is *my* wonderful *text*";
let regex = /(?<=\*)(.*?)(?=\*)/;
while (str.includes('*')) {
  let matched = regex.exec(str);
  let wrap = "<i>" + matched[1] + "</i>";
  str = str.replace(`*${matched[1]}*`, wrap);
}
console.log(str);
```

Comment: Holy infinite loop, Batman! Did you test this with a string containing a single asterisk? Why would to name a variable `arr` if it contains string type data?  How about ditching the loop and trying the `g` modifier?

Comment: sorry for my naming convection

Answer (score -1):

here you go my friend:

```js
var arr = "This is *my* wonderful *text*";
const matched = arr.match(/\*(?:.*?)\*/g);
for (let i = 0; i < matched.length; i++) {
  arr = arr.replace(matched[i], `<i>${matched[i].replaceAll("*", "")}</i>`);
}
console.log(arr);
```

an explanation first of all we're matching the regex globaly by setting /g **NOTE:** that match with global flag returns an array.
secondly we're looking for any character that lies between two astrisks and we're escaping them because both are meta characters.
**.*?** match everything in greedy way so we don't get something like this *my**.
?: for non capturing groups, then we're replacing every element we've matched with itself but without astrisk.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError`

Comment: did u run the snippet ?

Comment: you can run it to find out

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8FVdWqG
https://codepen.io/headsick/pen/KKMMpgP
here is a screenshot and pen working fine

Comment: I don't know why is not working but just see the error in the [console here](https://codepen.io/headsick/pen/KKMMpgP) is the same as the one in the snippet and in my browser

Comment: i'm not consoling it in the console i'm alerting it...

Comment: Rather than lazy quantifier matching, a negated character class seems more appropriate for this answer.  There is no need for looped `replace()` calls, please read about `g`